# My UI lags while trying to connect to a socket?

Tags: c#, sockets, xamarin

When I try to connect to my server socket, my interface lags, and the catch doesn't run.

Here's my code :

```cs
protected void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    if (!clientSocket.Connected)
    {
        try
        {
            clientSocket.Connect("172.20.10.4", 100);
        }
        catch (SocketException)
        {
            gettext.Text = "Couldn't Connect";
        }
    }
    SendLoop();
}

private void SendLoop()
{
    gettext.Text = "get ivi type";
    string req = gettext.Text;
    byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(req);
    clientSocket.Send(buffer);
    byte[] BuffRec = new byte[1024];
    int rec = clientSocket.Receive(BuffRec);
    byte[] data = new byte[rec];
    Array.Copy(BuffRec, data, rec);
    gettext.Text =  Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
}
```

As a result I'd like to display the exception message when I'm not connected to the socket.

Answer (score 1):

Simplistically, you need to do all this asyncronously. Your UI freezes (not lags - lagging implies it's going slowly but it is moving, it's just some time behind) because the thread that would ordinarily be busy drawing the UI and keeping it responding, is waiting on the connection to connect, then it's sending and receiving data

Where you've said `Connect`, `Send` and `Receive`, those need to be `ConnectAsync`, `SendAsync` and `ReceiveAsync`. You'll need to make other code changes to use async methods, such as marking your own methods as async and using the `await` keyword before method calls that could block.

By switching to using `xAsync` methods, when your UI is going to get blocked up waiting for a connection to complete, or for data to transfer, the code will pause what it's doing and go back to drawing the UI. When data is available etc, it will be called back to the point where it left off, and carry on processing

I also recommend you don't try to call `SendLoop` outside of your check whether the socket is connected..